# Segmentation of list to minimize the largest sum

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, object-oriented, dynamic-programming

I have written the following code for diving a list 'seq' into 'k' segments such that the maximum sum of each segment is minimized. I have used dynamic programming to solve this problem. But my class "Segmentation" seems a little overwhelmed with too many redundant functions. Can anybody give me a few suggestions on how can I improve this code? I am even using separate functions for returning boolean values and calculating the average. Also using `raise SystemExit` because I do not want to add new library only for this line. Please provide your valuable feedback on the below code.

```
"""
Calculate the optimal k-segmentation of a sequence using dynamic programming
Author: Jahid Chowdhury Choton (choton@ksu.edu)

The sub-problems for dynamic programming are given below:
Base case: Opt(i,j,M) = cost(S[:i]-M) if j==1
Recursion: Opt(i,j,M) = min( max( Opt(l,j-1, M), cost(S[l:i])-M) for l=1,2,...,i)
"""

class Segmentation:
    def __init__(self, seq, k):
        self.seq = seq
        self.k = k
        self.n = len(seq)
        self.M = self.avg()  # Parameter M is taken to be the average of the sequence
        self.opt_val, self.opt_segments = self.opt()  # Calculate optimal values and segmentation

    def avg(self):  # To calculate average of sequence seq
        return sum(self.seq) / self.n

    def is_odd(self, val):  # To return a boolean value 0 or 1
        return val % 2

    def initialize_cost_and_dp(self):  # To initialize cost array, DP array and traceback array
        cost_sum = [0] * (self.n + 1)  # Initialize cost array with zeros
        dp = [[-1.0 for _ in range(self.n+1)] for _ in range(2)]  # Tabulation array for DP
        tb = [[[] for _ in range(self.n+1)] for _ in range(2)]  # Traceback array for optimal segmentation
        for i in range(0, self.n):  # O(n)
            # Add the elements of the sequence seq into cost array
            cost_sum[i + 1] = self.seq[i] + cost_sum[i]
            # Initialize DP array with infinity values
            dp[0][i+1] = float('inf')
            dp[1][i+1] = float('inf')
        # print(cost_sum, dp, tb)
        return cost_sum, dp, tb

    def generate_segmentation(self, traceback):  # To generate k-segmentation of sequence seq using traceback array
        # Separate the traceback array into two parts starts and ends
        starts = traceback[self.is_odd(self.k)][self.n]
        ends = starts[1:] + [self.n]
        # print(starts, ends)
        k_segments = [self.seq[s:e] for s, e in zip(starts, ends)]  # Concatenate the two parts for optimal segments
        return k_segments

    def opt(self):  # To calculate the optimal value and segmentation using dp
        if self.n < self.k:
            print("Not enough cells for k-segmentation, now exiting the program...")
            raise SystemExit  # Program will terminate if k is less than the segmented cells
        costSum, dp, tb = self.initialize_cost_and_dp() # Get the initial values of cost array, DP array and TB array
        for i in range(1, self.k + 1):  # O(k)
            for j in range(1, self.n + 1):  # O(n)
                for l in range(i - 1, j):  # O(n-k)
                    curr_val = max(dp[self.is_odd(i - 1)][l],
                                   abs((costSum[j] - costSum[l]) - self.M))  # Check the current max value
                    prev_val = dp[self.is_odd(i)][j]  # Check the previous value
                    if curr_val < prev_val:  # Check the min value and update it in DP and traceback array
                        dp[self.is_odd(i)][j] = curr_val  # Update the min value in dp array
                        tb[i % 2][j] = tb[self.is_odd(i - 1)][l] + [l]  # Update the breakpoint in traceback array

        optimal_value = dp[self.is_odd(self.k)][self.n]  # Calculate the optimal value
        optimal_segments = self.generate_segmentation(tb)  # Generate the optimal segments
        return optimal_value, optimal_segments


# Driver Code
def main():
    # S = [3, 7, 7, 33]
    # S = [3, 4, 2, 2, 6, 7, 43, 100000, 4, 3, 11]
    # S = [3, 4, 2, 2, 6, 7, 43, 50, 43, 3, 11]
    # S = [3, 4, 2, 2, 6, 7, 13, 10, 43, 50, 5]
    # S = [1,1,1,5,5,5]
    S = [3,8,7,1,11]
    k = 3

    # Call the class Segmentation
    k_segmentation = Segmentation(S, k)

    # Get the optimal value and segmentation
    optimal_values = k_segmentation.opt_val
    optimal_segmentation = k_segmentation.opt_segments

    # Print the optimal value and segmentation
    print("Optimal value =", optimal_values)
    print("Optimal k-segmentation = ", optimal_segmentation)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One could approach this from the goal:

What is the business of a `Segmentation` instance, what are its business methods?   You tagged `object-oriented`: What is the value added by having a `Segmentation(sequence, k)` instance over an `opt(sequence, k)` function?

In your `main()`, you don't (syntactically) call *any* method of `k_segmentation`.
A first improvement would be to take the call to `opt()` out of the constructor, rendering "the `opt_…` attributes" obsolete.

While I can "see" the segmentation part `opt()` returns, what is that `optimal_value`?
Document both in a [docstring](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#documentation-strings) for `opt()`!

To get some advantage from a `Segmentation` instance, have it keep information useful for more than one access.
If you construct it with just the sequence and pass the number of parts as a parameter to `opt(k)`, you can look for information independent of `k` - `M` is, `cost_sum` looks a candidate.

---

- The methods are commented for what they do. Not bad.
  Docstrings would be even better, starting with `help(Segmentation.opt)`.
  With `opt()`, a description of how it works would add value.
- Naming
  • `is_odd()` is named for how it works - I'd prefer `current(i)` and `previous(i)`.
    (There is one instance of `i % 2` not substituted.)
  • `costSum` isn't snake_case (nor is `M`).
  • internal methods like `initialize_cost_and_dp` maybe should start with an underscore.
  • Method/function names with an *and* are a code smell.

From Python 3.10, `generate_segmentation()` could use `itertools.pairwise`.

---

I think all that indexing with `[self.is_odd(i)]` for *current* (`i - 1` for *previous*) reduces readability - if you want to keep the mechanism, you can use [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html)s -
I'd likely go for named attributes & an explicit swap at the end of the outer loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your useful comments. It really helped a lot!